# what is going wrong, Fatal error: Incorrect base_url

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

config.php is defined as following:

```
$base_config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sg-cms/';

    $base_config['db_host'] = 'localhost';
    $base_config['db_name'] = 'sg-cms';
    $base_config['db_user'] = 'root';
    $base_config['db_pass'] = '';

    $base_config['theme']   = 'basic';

    $base_config['allow_5_4'] = false;

    $base_config['salt']            = 'dfsfdsfdsfasfafasfsfadfvdfdfsfa';
    $base_config['encryption_key']  = 'bjAdffdsfdfadfaJv';
```

when going to loclhost I see the follwoing error:

> Fatal error: Incorrect base_url: 'http://localhost/sg-cms/' does not match 'http://localhost/SWEBSITES/t_m/website/index.php' in C:\wamp\www\SWEBSITES\t_m\website\includes\routing.php on line 277

what is going wrong here exactly because it seems like when I fix something another thing gets corrupted!

Comment: So what framework/CMS are you using?

Comment: its for my work, they have their own framework!!

Comment: I would create a Virtual Host for your project to run inside. This will sort out and clarify base urls [Here is how to a why its a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)